# Javascript - why is it possible to use includes method for object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
const obj1 = { name: "kim", age: 14 };
const obj2 = { name: "Steve", age: 20};
const arr  = [ obj1, obj2];

arr[0]["name"].includes("han"); // true
```

so this is the code that I am curious.
I think `includes()` method is for array, not for object.
but in this case arr is array but `arr[0]` is object. also `arr[0]["name"]` is property of object, then why is it possible to use   includes method on this code?
I would be grateful if someone tell me what I know wrong

Comment: It won't output `true`. Instead, it should give `false`. BTW you are using `includes` on a string, not on object. if you would have used any substring from `kim` then you would have got `true`

Comment: `arr[0]["name"]` (or `arr[0].name`, same thing) is a **string**. See [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes` on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or on [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

According to you code `includes` doesn't give `true` because It doesn't work on an object. Instead, you are using it on a string.

When you console

```
arr[0]["name"]   // kim
```

And what your code is checking is whether `han` is a substring of `kim` or not. As we know it's not so it will output `false`

```js
const obj1 = { name: "kim", age: 14 };
const obj2 = { name: "Steve", age: 20 };
const arr = [obj1, obj2];

console.log(arr[0]["name"]);
console.log(arr[0]["name"].includes("m"));
```

Answer (score 0):

includes() check if a sub string is present in the given string.

In your case :

```js
arr[0]["name"].includes("han")
```

It should return false, as "kim" does not include "han".

Comment: You should elaborate to give as many details as possible.